# Grouped Recyclerview only showing one column on child

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a Android Java app with a grouped recycler view. The app is maded with Mvvm pattern. I have headers who also have recyclerviews, and I show or hide it based on a value. The list loads ok, and the hide/show works ok, but I don't get two columns on the child recyclerview.

This is the Header Item:

```
<layout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
            <import type="android.view.View"/>
            <variable
                name="model"
                type="package.ItemCredentialHeader" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="@{model.title}"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        tools:text="TITLE"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerclick"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Hide"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <!--Child RecyclerView-->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/child_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:itemsAdapter="@{model.credentialsList}"
                android:visibility="@{model.folded ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:spanCount="2"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_credential" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="package.ItemCredentialProfile" />
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/background_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/credentialData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:text="@{model.data}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:text="DATO" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:text="@{model.typeName}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:text="Type" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@{model.issuer}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Issuer" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_status"
            android:statusColor="@{model.status}"
            tools:backgroundTint="@color/status_green">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="3dp"
                android:statusText="@{model.status}"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                tools:text="status" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_card_left">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:text="View detail >"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue_900"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </FrameLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the RecyclerView

```
           <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/actions_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:itemClick="@{viewModel}"
                    android:itemsAdapter="@{viewModel.headersList}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_credential_header"/>
```

That is how Android studio shows me the list:

[image]

But that's what I got on the device...

[image]

It doesn't matter how much groups or elements I have I only get one column

Answer (score 1):

So... at the end it was all my fault...
I was setting the layout manager this way

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:itemsAdapter"})
public static void addItems(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            LiveData<List<ListItem>> actions) {
    if(actions!=null && actions.getValue()!=null) {
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(actions.getValue());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

I solved just adding a new binding adapter for the child recyclerview

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:itemsGridAdapter"})
public static void addItemsToGrid(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            LiveData<List<ListItem>> actions) {
    if(actions!=null && actions.getValue()!=null) {
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(actions.getValue());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(),2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}
```